# Attempted to cause memory leak intentionally, but it disappeared after the program finished

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, memory-management, memory-leaks

For purely studying purpose, I wrote the following code to cause a memory leak:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void reserve_memory(){
  double* ptr = new double[10000000];
}

int main(){ // memory leak experiment
  for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){
    reserve_memory();
  }
  std::cout << "sleeping now" << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
}
```

At the same time of running the above program, I was observing the memory usage using `htop` command, and I observed that the memory usage was actually glowed. But after the program finishes, the the memory seems to be released according to the panel in `htop`. Do you know why the memory leak disappear?  I'm using ubuntu 18.04, and also curious if it is the case for other operating systems.

Comment: The memory is owned by the starting process and goes away when the process ends :)

Comment: try making it global

Comment: The memory leak occurs when `reserve_memory` returns, because it allocated memory (with `new`) and threw away the pointer to that memory. Because the pointer is gone, there is no way that your program can use that memory. That's the leak. Most operating systems will clean up after you, so memory leaks don't have long term consequences.